# Read Encoded string from .dbf file

Tags: string, encoding, char, decoding, dbf

There is a `.dbf` file and I want to read its data but the strings are unreadble.
I don not know the encoding of the strings!! 
Can I find it out?
Is it possible to get the encoding of strings in a `.dbf` file? 
Is it possible to get an unreadable string from `.dbf` file?
Is it possible to get an unreadable string which is encoded in ANSI?
because the string is unreadable, Does this mean it is encoded in some way??

**EDIT:**

below code is how I connect to the `.dbf` file  and read it

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
    {

        var sql =
            "select name, family, account, is_no, code, bdate, is_pl, father from CP where account like '%23854%' ";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
        con.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);

        var dt = ds.Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            var account = row["account"];
        }
    }
```

and it returns 23854æ∞ì as account.

**EDIT2:**

I used some third party to find some info about my .dbf file, and below picture shows that

[image]

**EDIT3:**

here is the screenshot of data with [DBF Commander Pro](http://dbf-software.com/)

the unreadable chars are in `Arabic/Persian`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

***After edits:***

So now the sole problem is to the conversion.

The desired encodings could be (I searched in Wikipedia):

- "ISO-639-1"
- "ISO-639-2"
- "ISO-639-3"

Either:

```
private static String getAsciz(byte[] bytes, int offset, int offset2) {
    for (int i = offset; i < offset2; ++i) {
        if (bytes[i] == 0) {
            offset2 = i;
        }
    }
    final String encoding = "ISO-639-1";
    try {
        return new String(bytes, offset, offset2 - offset, encoding).trim();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Charset not installed: " + encoding);
    }
}
```

Or when using a third-party library maybe hacking by undoing the encoding (be aware that this might be a variable encoding: the current platform encoding):

```
String s = thirdParty.getColumn("NAME");

// Reconstruct the bytes (Windows Latin-1, Western Europe)
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("Cp1252");

s = new String(bytes, "ISO-639-1");
```

---

***Old answer:***

`.dbf` is a binary format of records with fixed length. Of every record the field values are normal character arrays (ANSI most likely).

My guess is, you try to read the file as text.

Or the .dbf file is encrypted. Look into the file with a hex editor.

---

You can read it as binary blocks. First comes a header part with column definitions. Then come the actual records with a deletion marker.

As this is an old format, there are numerous libraries. You did not mention which programming language to use, but with the use of a hex dump and maybe some format info in the internet, you can easily make a dbf reader.

---

***A simple conversion to tab-separated-text:***

Untested and in java, but showing that it is trivial. You can then use Excel or so for conversion and OLE DB. Note: as input `in` I use ISO-8859-1 here, and as output `out` UTF-8. I also write a BOM (begin of file marker) for UTF-8 recognition.

```
private static final boolean TEST = true;

private static class FieldDef {
    String name;
    char type;
    int length;
    int decimals;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File dbfFile = new File("C:/aaa/bbb.dbf");
    String csvName = dbfFile.getName().replaceFirst("(?i)\\.dbf$", "") + ".csv";
    File csvFile = new File(dbfFile.getParentFile(), csvName);
    try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(dbfFile));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(csvFile, "UTF-8")) {
        byte[] header = new byte[0x20];
        in.read(header);

        // Version:
        switch (header[0x00]) {
            case 0x03:
                System.out.println("dBaseIII without Memo");
                break;
            case -128 + 0x03:
                System.out.println("dBaseIII with Memo");
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("dBase Version not 3");
        }

        int recordCount = getInt(header, 0x04);
        int headerSize = getShort(header, 0x08);
        int recordSize = getShort(header, 0x0a);

        List<FieldDef> fieldDefs = new ArrayList<>();
        byte[] fieldDefBytes = new byte[0x20];
        int offset = header.length;
        out.print("\uFFFE"); // UTF-8 BOM to distinghuish it from Windows ANSI.
        out.print("DEL"); // Deletion marker.
        while (offset + 1 < headerSize) {
            in.read(fieldDefBytes);
            FieldDef fieldDef = new FieldDef();
            fieldDef.name = getAsciz(fieldDefBytes, 0, 11);
            fieldDef.type = (char)fieldDefBytes[11];
            // #4 int - field data address.
            fieldDef.length = 0xFF & fieldDefBytes[16];
            fieldDef.decimals = 0xFF & fieldDefBytes[17];
            out.print('\t');
            out.print(fieldDef.name);
            fieldDefs.add(fieldDef);
            System.out.printf("%-11s %c (%d, %d)%b", fieldDef.name,
                    fieldDef.type, fieldDef.length, fieldDef.decimals);
        }
        out.println();
        int b = in.read();
        assert b == 0x0d;

        byte[] record = new byte[recordSize];
        for (int recno = 0; recno < recordCount; ++recno) {
            if (TEST && recno > 100) {
                break;
            }
            in.read(record);
            //boolean deleted = (0xFF & record[0]) != 0x20; // == 0x2A '*'
            String deletionMark = getAsciz(record, 0, 1);
            out.print(deletionMark);
            offset = 1;
            for (FieldDef fieldDef : fieldDefs) {
                out.print('\t');
                String fieldValue = getAsciz(record, offset, offset + fieldDef.length);
                out.print(fieldValue);
                offset += fieldDef.length;
            }
            out.println();
        }
        // assert in.read() == 0x1A; // End-of-file byte.
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Dbf3ToTsv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private static int getInt(byte[] bytes, int offset) {
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        n = (n << 8) | (0xFF & bytes[offset + 4 - 1 - i]);
    }
    return n;
}

private static int getShort(byte[] bytes, int offset) {
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        n = (n << 8) | (0xFF & bytes[offset + 2 - 1 - i]);
    }
    return n;
}

private static String getAsciz(byte[] bytes, int offset, int offset2) {
    for (int i = offset; i < offset2; ++i) {
        if (bytes[i] == 0) {
            offset2 = i;
        }
    }
    return new String(bytes, offset, offset2 - offset, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).trim();
}
```

Comment: I am using `C#` and I've used `OleDbConnection` to connect to this DB and `OleDbCommand` for query the database..is this way right??

Comment: I've seen the `.dbf` in hex editor..what was the point for hex editor? (sorry if it is clear but for me it is not!!)

Comment: I thought you were reading the file itself. Then a hex dump would show the format. With an OleDbConnection everything should work; maybe there is an encryption problem; also there are different dBase versions. But I think it likely to be encryption. **Uncheck my answer, to keep in the running.**

Comment: I could explore your file in details, if you'll attach it.

Comment: @Oleg, the file is too large...about 7 millions of records

Comment: @JoopEggen, what do you mean by encryption problem...Do you mean it is encrypted in a bad way or I read the data in a bad way?? I use `OleDbDataAdapter`  and `dataset` and when I see data it is unreadable(very bad format), but I am sure there is valid data in the file.

Comment: There exists a rarely used option to encrypt a dBase table. If you cannot see text, say in the hex dump, of string field values, then that could have been a cause. It could also be that the dBase version is other than OleDb can read. Try other software first, a viewer or converter.

Comment: @JoopEggen, I've shared some new info about `.dbf` file, any Idea??

Comment: dBase 3 has an other format than 4 if I remember correctly. I will give a bit of pseudo-code, as I am not a C# programmer, to convert the file to tab-separated-values.

Answer (score 1):

A `.dbf` file is a mixed binary and encoded text file format. By `encoded` I don't mean encryption, I mean coded into a codepage depending on the language used for the `.dbf` file (such as cp1252 (Windows English) or cp1251 (Cyrillic).

If you want program access and control then you need to either write your own library, or use one of the many already out there.

If you are correctly using a library and still getting nonsense, it may be encrypted, or the file may have been corrupted.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is not any corruption..as I said in my above comment, I use `OleDbCommand` and `OleDbDataAdapter` and `Dataset`..but it returns unreadable data, I dont know about encryption and how can I handle that!!..for example if I decrypt the data then it should work?? I can query the file and I read it as text.

Comment: Feel free to contact me privately if you'd like me to check out the dbf file itself.  By `encryption` we mean that it has been password protected, and the contents scrambled using that password.

Comment: Thank you, It is really great..I really do not know how to read the file but the compressed file size is 187M.

Comment: I've shared some new info about `.dbf` file, any Idea??

Comment: The size doesn't matter to me.  Looking at your print screens three things jump out at me:  1) DBF Commander Pro does not tell you what encoding the file is in; and 2) either the wrong encoding is being used to interpret those bytes, or it's encrypted; and 3) if BDATE is supposed to a date of some sort, then (2) definitely applies.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the file with [DBF Commander Pro](http://dbf-software.com). It supports dBase 3. If the file will be opened, please share a screenshot of the table. Maybe there is just a wrong encoding in your file and you just need to set correct charset flag. If so, click Tools -> Set Codepage, then choose the appropriate encoding from the list.

Comment: Thanks, I've just added the screenshot, and I tried all the available codepages in software but all of them showed unreadable data.

Comment: I should mention that these unreadable chars are  `Arabic/Persian` (do not know which one exactly).

Comment: Well, it looks like there is no encoded data, because the only characters are unreadable, while numerics are correct. I still think that there is some trouble with character set. Could you please execute the following SQL query: `SELECT * FROM table_name INTO DBF "D:\table1.dbf", then send the result DBF file to us on support [a] elphsoft.com. We'll try to "play" with charsets.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean under 'sql db' format, but the point is that I'd like to see unchanged original DBF data. But if the symbols in 'sql db' file are the same as you see in the DBF file - let's try. I'll create new DBF file and insert these data manually.

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks like the `Iran System` encoded data. It's a very special encoding which was in use in early DOS days (FoxPro days!) in Iran. You can find a C# converter for it here: https://github.com/mohsen-d/IranSystemConvertor

[More info](http://www.dotnettips.info/newsarchive/details/926#comment-570) (in Persian)

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work correctly for me! there are some '?' chars in every conversion.

Comment: So does it work or not? or it just works partially? If it works partially, try `OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0` http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839 with this connection string: `var connectionString = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=D:\path\rep.dbf;Password=;Collating Sequence=MACHINE";`

Answer (score 0):

Salam,
Try changing windows settings in control panel

- Regione and Language
- Administrative
- Change System local...
- Arabic(Algeria) or Persian

And the dbf data will be readable